# How can I get the index of the rows, from a data.frame with repeated cases, after using the unique() function?

Tags: r, indexing, rows

I am cleaning my database 'Visitas' and as it is formed by patients that come over the hospital once a week, so I have the same subject repeated many times while I'm just interested in taking into account the patient once.

I used the `unique()` function to get the 'real' number of patients but now I cannot take it from the original database.

I tried to create a vector with those cases and then use a which() in order to get the indexes but it doesn't work.

I leave some code below.

```
# Visitas_act: active patients who are still going to the hospital
# Visitas_mod: the initial 'Visitas' database but almost cleaned.
# codeep: patient code, identifier

Visitas_mod <- Visitas_mod[Visitas_act, ]
unique(Visitas_mod[, 'codeep'])
Visitas_r <- unique(Visitas_mod[, 'codeep'])
```

I tried this but it doesn't work because the indexes doesn't match then in the 'Visitas_mod' database

```
tut <- which(Visitas_mod[, 'codeep'] == Visitas_r)    
Visitas_mod <- Visitas_mod[tut, ]
```

Comment: Hi @CarlosPascualBosch, i don't quite get what you are trying to do. So with ```Visitas_r``` you get a unique vector of patient code. What do you need from the original data frame? you cannot use  == when the right hand side is a vector. You can use %in% but.. i still don't get your logic

Comment: It is already answered but thank you for your interest. My purpose was to get the indexes of the 'Visitas_r' patients, the code patients (codeep) which are not repeated, in order to extract them from the original database 'Visitas_mod' to just work with the active patients. Sorry for my expresion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont completly uderstand your question but my best guess is something like this, if you have any questions or i was mistaken just comment :)

```
#create dummy names
names <- cbind(row.names(mtcars),c(1:32))
visit <- sample(names[,1],400,replace = T)
df <- as.data.frame(x = visit)
id <- names[match(df$visit,names),2]
df <- cbind(df,id)


#get vector of unique visitors
uniqV <- unique(df$visit)
#this returns the index of first occurence of a visitor in the dataframe
match(uniqV,df$visit)
```

Output:

```
 1   2   3   5   6   7   8   9  11  12  13  14  15  20  21  23  24  25  28  30  32  37  46
47  53  58  64  68  85  90 107 120
```

All positions can be done with this continued part of the code

```
#return all position of unique visitor in dataset
test <- function(x) {
  which(df$visit %in% x)
}

matches <- sapply(uniqV,test)

out <- cbind(as.character(uniqV), unlist(lapply(matches, paste, collapse =",")))
```

Output:

```
1   Ford Pantera L  1,98,116,127,128,136,142,189,208,210,217,254,273,275,277,298,313,360
2   Hornet Sportabout   2,19,29,78,81,112,144,234,294,303,322,332,387
3   Merc 280C   3,4,39,159,173,188,308,309,312,351,389
4   Merc 230    5,18,48,77,106,150,161,211,219,240,241,270,299,306,330,365,383
5   Dodge Challenger    6,74,154,172,222,268,336,352,367
6   Valiant 7,26,207,235,258,265,392,397
7   Porsche 914-2   8,45,102,113,117,119,121,131,149,151,224,288,329,343,350,362,394
8   Fiat X1-9   9,10,65,95,135,170,271,282,285,346,380
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the match() function and now it works, I got the indexes of the non-repeated values. Sorry for my expression it was my first time here.

Comment: no problem, it was a fun question to solve, I'm too very new to replying to questions, I'm happy that i could help you :)